# Can not use DisplayAttribute in T4 template

Tags: c#, .net, code-generation, t4, texttemplate

In my custom T4 template I have to read `DisplayAttribute` of a `type`. But I'm keep getting different errors after struggling with several solutions.
Here is part of my `.tt` file :

```
<#@ template debug="true" hostspecific="true" language="C#" compilerOptions="/langversion:10" #>
<#@ assembly name="System" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Runtime" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.ComponentModel.Annotations" #>

<#@ import namespace="System" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Reflection" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Runtime" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations" #> 
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>

<#
    static string GetEnumValueDisplayName(Enum value)
    {
        Type type = value.GetType();
        MemberInfo[] memInfo = type.GetMember(value.ToString());
        DisplayAttribute? dispalyAttribute = null;
        if (memInfo != null && memInfo.Length > 0)
        {
            object[] attrs = memInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute), false);

            if (attrs != null && attrs.Length > 0)
                dispalyAttribute = attrs[0] as DisplayAttribute;
        }
        return dispalyAttribute?.Name ?? "";
    }
#>


<#
 foreach(myEnum en in Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum)))
 {#>
          public static class <#=@en.ToString()#> { public const string Value = "<#=@en.ToString()#>";public const string Text = "<#=@GetEnumValueDisplayName(en)#>";}
<#}#>
```

And here is my compile time error :

> Compiling transformation: The type name 'DisplayAttribute' could not
> be found in the namespace 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations'.
> This type has been forwarded to assembly
> 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations, Version=4.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' Consider adding a
> reference to that assembly.

I am using .net 6 with Visual Studio 2022(17.0.4).

Comment: VS 22 17.0.4 is from 2021, any particular reason you can't update?

Comment: @Lennart I don't think It has anything to do with version of  VS since the T4 is around for many years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am using .net 6

That would be a problem. The VS T4 engine only supports .NET Framework at this point, which means that it cannot load any .NET Core libraries during the transformation. We have started working on a .NET Core version of the engine but there is no ETA on when this would become available. Any updates would be communicated through this [Suggestion Ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/881587/support-loading-of-net-core-libraries-in-t4-templa.html).

Answer (score 0):

Remove `<#@ assembly name="System.ComponentModel.Annotations" #>` and add `using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;` to the regular using statements.

[image]

Comment: this is not the answer. I updated the code to be more accurate. I want to use DisplayNameAttribute as part of generation code not as part of generated code.